# .htaccess URL Rewrite for not existing dynamic URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We had to close one of the our e-commerce site and have to deal with 404's after permanent redirection.

We have approx. 10K url like below. All of them starts with /gproductinfo~p_template

http://www.domainname.com/gproductinfo~p_template-1-PID-7791-mypage-0-combo_src_siz-0-combo_src_pri-0-combo_src_ord-0-combo_src_cat-122-combo_src_rpp-0-c_type-0-c_color-0-c_weave-0-c_material-0-c_shape-0

I would like to 301 all requests which starts /gproductinfo~p_template to another another domain.

I will appreciate any help.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The htaccess to detect the gproductinfo

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} gproductinfo~p_template
RewriteRule ^gproductinfo~p_template(.*)$ newproduct$1 [S=1]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domainname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example-new.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will give you a 301 redirect to

```
http://www.example-new.com/newproduct-1-PID-7791-mypage-0-combo_src_siz-0-combo_src_pri-0-combo_src_ord-0-combo_src_cat-122-combo_src_rpp-0-c_type-0-c_color-0-c_weave-0-c_material-0-c_shape-0
```

Here are the resources I used to figure this out.

http://www.gerillafilm.se/web/ultimate-htaccess-rewrite-tutorial-with-301-redirects/

http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html

Comment: If you don't want to rewrite the gproductinfo to newproduct, simply remove the RewriteRule but leave the condition for it since that is what was needed